# ServiceLinkedRoleNotFoundFault error with Terraform and AWS Memory DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a memoryDB cluster using this module: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-memory-db

Below is my main code:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "redis_public_access" {
  name        = "allow_redis_public_access"
  description = "Allow Public Access to Redis"
  vpc_id      = my_vpc

  ingress {
    from_port        = 6379
    to_port          = 6379
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}

resource "random_password" "redis_pwd" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}

resource "random_string" "redis_user" {
  length  = 8
  special = false
  upper   = false
  numeric = false
}

module "memory_db" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/memory-db/aws"

  # Cluster
  name        = "redis-${local.env_type}"
  description = "MemoryDB cluster"
  security_group_ids         = [aws_security_group.redis_public_access.id]

  # Users
  users = {
    admin = {
      user_name     = random_string.redis_user.result
      access_string = "on ~* &* +@all" # give access to all available keys and commands: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/clusters.acls.html
      passwords     = [random_password.redis_pwd.result]
    }
  }

  create_parameter_group = false
  create_subnet_group    = false
  subnet_ids             = my_subnets.id
}
```

However, when I apply this, I am having the following error:

```
error creating MemoryDB User (deqwlktr): ServiceLinkedRoleNotFoundFault: This action cannot be completed due to insufficient permissions. (Recommended action) Please create new role using IAM API CreateServiceLinkedRole.
```

I have no idea what I should do to allow memory DB creating new users. Any idea what I should do? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem occured because I am on a region where Memory DB is not provided (eu-west-3). As soon as I used a supported region, it worked.

Here is the list of the supported regions for memory DB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/regionsandazs.html